# How to access multiple model data from an eloquent call

Tags: laravel

I currently have a `product` table with the following columns:

```
id, product_name, product_type, description
```

I also have three more tables:

```
 medias, attributes, coatings
```

each of those tables has an `id, name, description, img`

Each product created din the product table will have multiple, medias, attributes and coatings.  To address this I created a table `product_relations` which contains the columns:

```
id, product_id, media_id, attribute_id, coating_id
```

From here I thought I would make a call to product_relations with the product_id and then pull each record so I can access the data.  However I'm stuck on how I would do this as an eloquent relationship.  Would I do separate has many's in my Product_Relation model like so:

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Media');
}

public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attributes');
}
```

etc? Or is there a simpler way to build this to access all that at once?

Comment: you should create `polymorphic` table for this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: table will be `productables` then columns `product_id,productable_id,productable_type`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships